# I am trying the for statement to clear the list, but it fails. How is the for statement executed?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
 sum=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
 for figure in sum:
    print(list(sum))
    print(figure)
    sum.remove(min(sum))
    print(figure)
    print(list(sum))
    print('\n')
 print(list(sum))
```

Comment: Don't change the length of a list while iterating over it!

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: why  .just I find about iterating with google,but I can not understand it,

Comment: I am trying to use the for statement, I get an error, so I use print to check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't change the length of the iterable while iterating over it. If you want to print the minimum item and delete it until the list is empty, you should loop on the condition of the list beein empty, something like this:

```
sum=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
while sum:
    print(min(sum))
    sum.remove(min(sum))
```

output:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
```

The problem of changing the iterable length is that python's interpreter basically will try to get the next element based on the previous position on the list.

For example, if you loop trough:

```
[a,b,c,d]
```

the first item will be `a` (the item on `index 0`). The next iteration of the for loop it will try to retrieve the item on `index 1` but if you remove `a`, the ìndex `1` will not be `b` anymore, because your current list will look like this;

```
[b,c,d]
```

and the `index 1`is now `c`, skipping every other item on neext iterations

Comment: Additional: The list shouldn't be called `sum` because it overwrites the builtin [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum).

Answer (score 0):

if you want to clear the whole list, the use the inbuilt function `clear()`. below is the example how to do that.

```
lis=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
print('printing original list',lis,sep=' : ')
# output printing original list : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9] 
lis.clear()
print('printing new cleared list',lis,sep=' : ')
# output printing new cleared list : []
```